# Retrieve server_side Ajax Loaded DataTable data from an external URL using PHP

Tags: php, datatables

How I can retrieve the datatable data from the URL which uses Ajax sourced data.

For example URL1: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html
Table ID: #example

For example URL2: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side
Table ID: #example

I tried to retrieve with simple dom, however, it brings html and table title but empty values. I think it is because values are loaded with Ajax afterwards. I have used below table. It works on on other tables except ajax sourced data.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/src/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html');

$tr = $html->find('table[id=example] tr');

foreach ($tr as $row) {
    foreach ($row->find('td') as $td) {
        echo $td->plaintext.'<br/>';
    }
    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

I have also tried curling URL, but again table is empty.

```
function sovbetov_curl_content($url, $json = false, $show_error = false) {
if (!function_exists('curl_init')) { return file_get_contents($url); } // fallback
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === false && $show_error) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . curl_error($ch)."n";
}
curl_close($ch);
if ($json) {
    return json_decode($response, true);
}
return $response;
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for comments. Upon suggesstion of @Dimitris Filippou, I have looked for ajax request data source. The website I am targeting to retrieve data is using this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
assetListVM = { 
dt: null, init: function () { 
    dt = $('#offersImport').dataTable({ 
        "dom": dataTableDom, 
        "serverSide": true, 
        "processing": true, 
        "ajax": { 
            "url": "/Trade/OffersImportTable", 
            "type": "POST", 
            "datatype": "json", 
            "dataSrc": function (d) { console.log(d); return d.data.rows; } 
        }
```

So, I tried to request data with similar ajax from mentioned URL, but it says Access to XMLHttpRequest at Target-URL from origin My-URL has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

So, I guess there is no way to retrieve data from that URL.

Comment: You can look at the request and see that the data for the table comes from this [url](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/data/arrays.txt?_=1640092678776)

Comment: I think [this page](https://www.datatables.net/manual/ajax) does a better job of explaining DataTables Ajax.

Comment: I noticed this, how they load data (another website)
$(document).ready(function () {
assetListVM = {
dt: null,
init: function () {
dt = $('#offersImport').dataTable({
"dom": dataTableDom,
"serverSide": true,
"processing": true,
"ajax": {
 "url": "/Trade/OffersImportTable",
 "type": "POST",
 "datatype": "json",
 "dataSrc": function (d) {
  console.log(d);
  return d.data.rows;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some browser emulator based on PHP, like [Mink](https://mink.behat.org/en/latest/). You probably can't get data, generated by Javascript, in any other way using PHP.